# React: When navigating away from mounted component, show it again if click browser back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is a part of my root component code:

```
 const App = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/products">
                <AllProducts />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/teams">
                <AllTeams />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
        {isVisible && (
            <Overlay />
        )}
    );
};
```

I have a Home component, from where I can navigate to other pages using a router. In Home component I have a button and when clicking on it, I set `isVisible` variable to true and `<Overlay />` component is being opened as an overlay (similar to modal) and when it's open, the `/` pathname does not change, because it's outside router. There may be many links and I can navigate to other routes, for example `/teams` and also go much more deeper away from it. And the question is, if I hit the browser back button at some point, how to show this `<Overlay />`, like it were in the browser history?

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a [query param](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

> A query string is a part of a uniform resource locator (URL) that assigns values to specified parameters.